# Range based for implicitly adds `const` qualifier?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, initializer-list

Let's look at the following simple range based for loop:

```
  int a = 5, b = 6;
  for (auto & i : {a, b})
  {
      std::cout << i << std::endl; // Works as expected.
      i = 3;                       // Error!
  }
```

`gcc` complains about `assignment of read-only reference 'i'`, implying that the range based for loop used with an initializer list implicitly adds a `const` qualifier to the reference, totally unprovoked.

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a work around to allow modifying variables in a range based for loop?

Comment: Well, I do not quite understand how this syntax (`auto & i : {a, b}`) works, but obviously `{a,b}` gives some `const` object. As if it was `const std::vector<int> v; for (auto& i : v)` then `i` will be `const` too.

Comment: What is the type of {a,b}. Never seen that before! Good to see this here :-)

Comment: @Klaus It's kind of a special case in the C++ standard. Unless some other cases apply first, `{...}` is deduced to `std::initialiser_list<T>`.

Comment: @Klaus: Scott's take on this construct: http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.at/2014/03/if-braced-initializers-have-no-type-why.html

Comment: @MFH: Thanks a lot for that link. Actually there is no day without wondering about the new language c++11/14. And no day where I not run into a compiler bug :-)  All compiler developers working on new features but all is only done by 95%. Bug fixing seems not a topic anymore :-(-. Hard time for developers...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In

```
int a = 5, b = 6;
for (auto & i : {a, b})
```

You have that `{a, b}` is an `std::initialiser_list` of two elements, `a` and `b`, in which the values of `a` and `b` are copied. Now, `std::initializer_list` [only provides constant iterators to its elements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin), because `initializer_list`s are immutable, so you cannot bind the value to non-`const` lvalue references.

One option would be to pass pointers instead, which would make the pointers themselves constant, but not the value they point to:

```
for (auto& i : {&a, &b}) 
    *i = 0;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d374c92dbe6e45e)

Another alternative would be to use an `std::reference_wrapper`, but that would still required a call to `.get()` or an explicit cast `static_cast<int&>` in this case:

```
for (auto& i : {std::ref(a), std::ref(b)}) 
    i.get() = 0;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c94d7e89757fcc80)

Considering that `std::reference_wrapper` [has an implicit conversion operator to `T&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get), I wouldn't be surprised if in some other context you would be able to automatically trigger an implicit conversion (as opposed to calling `.get()`).

---

Also note that `{a, b}` is not a range of numbers from `a` to `b`, it's really just those two numbers. So with `int a = 0, b = 10` you would not have `[0, 10]` but the list of `0` followed by `10`.

If you want to have "proper" ranges, I recommend you take a look at [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: So to answer question 2, I would need to do: `for (auto i : {&a, &b}) *i = 3`? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with range-based loops. The issue is that `std::initializer_list<int>::iterator` is `const int*`. You can't alter the contents of an `initializer_list`. If you were to use a type like `std::vector<int>` instead, this would work fine.

Comment: Or `std;;array` since it's small and fixed.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting to use `std::vector`, just saying that it would compile.